# How to justify the equivalence $A \lor \neg B \lor C\lor (\neg D \wedge E)\equiv (A \lor\neg B \lor C \lor\neg D)\wedge(A\lor\neg B\lor C \lor E)$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-explanation

Looking over some of my past work where I planned to convert expressions into 3CNF, I found the following step:

$A \lor \neg B \lor C\lor (\neg D \wedge E)\equiv (A \lor\neg B \lor C \lor\neg D)\wedge(A\lor\neg B\lor C \lor E)$

Can someone elucidate what rule(s) are used to establish that this is true?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Firstly, $\lor$ is associative, so we may suggestively write e.g.:

$$A \lor \neg B \lor C \lor (\neg D \land E) = (A \lor \neg B \lor C) \lor (\neg D \land E)$$

If we then define $X = A \lor \neg B \lor C$, we are left with:

$$X \lor (\neg D \land E) = (X \lor \neg D) \land (X\lor E)$$

which is precisely the statement that $\land$ *distributes* over $\lor$.

Together these statements yield the desired identity.

Comment: Thank you! I think that answers my question completely.